# Use of unresolved identifier 'checkOrientation' Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

When I Try Type Return My Func I Get This Error In AppDalgate.Swift

AppDalgate.Swift

```
  func application (application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return checkOrientation(self.window?.rootViewController)

    }
```

This Code For ViewController.Swift

```
  func checkOrientation(viewController:UIViewController?)-> Int{

        if(viewController == nil){

            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)//All means all orientation

        }else if (viewController is LoginViewController){

            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)//This is sign in view controller that i only want to set this to portrait mode only

        }else{

            return checkOrientation(viewController!.presentedViewController)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is also unclear what you seek to gain by recursively calling `checkOrientation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your App Delegate does not have access to functions in your View Controller. If you want to achieve this, one option would be to add a variable to the `AppDelegate` and set it equal to an instantiated `ViewController` Like so:

```
//Add this to your AppDelegate Outside of the methods.
var vc = ViewController()
```

After doing this, you can access the ViewController's methods from the AppDelegate like so:

```
//Inside a method of AppDelegate
//Replace ... with your parameters
vc.checkOrientation(...)
```

HOWEVER, keep in mind this is not the same instance of the `ViewController` class that your app will use when the app has finished launching. So if you try to use a method that references data that is added after the app has launched, it will not work.

Also, keep in mind that the `AppDelegate` should be kept as concise as possible for performance reasons.

Furthermore, you should probably change your `checkOrientation` function to:

```
func checkOrientation(viewController:UIViewController?)-> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if viewController is LoginViewController {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
}
```

Lastly, consider removing `checkOrientation` entirely and putting its logic in `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow`. Example:

```
func application (application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
   if self.window?.rootViewController is LoginViewController {
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
   } else {
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  How Make It To Access To Function In My View

Comment: Ok Just I Get This Error When I Type Your Edit Code  Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' @lke10

Comment: Change your `checkOrientation` to return type `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` and remove the `.rawValue` and casts to type `Int`. @kvra13 (As shown in my new edits).

Comment: I would also consider moving the logic of `checkOrientation` directly to `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` @kvra13 and getting rid of `checkOrientation`

Comment: You mean like this return vc.check Orientation (Int (UIInterfaceOrientation Mask.All.rawValue)) @lke10

Comment: @kvra13 , I updated my answer with what I meant. Look at the very end.

Comment: @kvra13 no problem! :D